How would I negate this mathematical statement (Basic Set Theory)?
Negate the following: For all $x\in G$, there exists a region $R$ such that $x\in R\subset G$.
I am struggling with how to interpret "$x\in R\subset G$". Is this the same as "$x\in R$ and $R\subset G$"? In that case, would the negation of the whole statement be: There exists $x\in G$ such that, for all regions $R$, $x\in R$ or $R\not\subset G$?

If $x\in R$ for all $x\in G$, then necessarily $G\subset R$.

Do you work with a specific definition of region, or is it just any subset? Do you interpret $\subset$ as $\subseteq$ or proper subset?

@fweth Our definition of region is as follows: If $a,b\in C$, where $C$ is a continuum, then the set of points $x$ such that $a<x<b$ is a region denoted $_{ab}$. For us, $\subset$ is the same as $\subseteq$.

The negation of "for all $x$, $P(x)$" is "there exists an $x$ such that $\mathrm{not}(P(x))$."
So here, it would be "there exists $x\in G$ such that "it is not the case that there exists an $R$ such that $R$ is a region, and $x\in R$, and $R\subset G$".
The negation of "there exists $R$ such that $Q(R)$" is "for all $R$, $\mathrm{not}(Q(R))$". So the negation of "there exists an $R$ such that $R$ is a region, and $x\in R$, and $R\subset G$" is "for all $R$, either $R$ is not a region, or $x$ is not in $R$, or $R$ is not contained in $G$". Because "(not T) or S" is equivalent to "T implies S", we can write this as

There exist $x\in G$ such that for every region $R$, either $x\notin R$ or $R\not\subset G$.

or

There exists $x\in G$ such that for every region $R$, if $x\in R$ then $R\not\subset G$.

or

There exists $x\in G$ such that for every region $R$, if $R\subset G$ then $x\notin R$.

There are other ways to phrase the negation, but those are probably the most parsable.
